# pd.read_sql slow for first query of certain type

Tags: sql, pandas, pyodbc

I am running into a performance issue when I read data from certain types of SQL queries into pandas dataframes. I begin by querying a SQL DB in Azure using code like this:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(db_conn_str)
starttime = timeit.default_timer()   
sql = "Select * from table where var1 != 'a' and var2 = 'b' and var3 = 'c' and var4 = 'd'"
outdata = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn)   
print("Elapsed time :", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)
```

This tends to take around 20-30 seconds. If I rerun the above query or if I run another query where 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd' are different within the next 20 minutes or so, the query only takes about 0.5 seconds. After 20 minutes have elapsed, the next query of this type will take 20-30 seconds.

Other types of queries take shorter amounts of time (e.g. ones where I only restrict using var2) and I have tried running those queries first, but the first query using the code above will still take 20-30 seconds.

I suppose this has something to do with the SQL DB? Can someone explain why I see this happening? Is there any way to prevent the first query from taking so much longer?

Comment: This query should return no rows because it has conflicted comparisons for `var3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
select *
from table
where var1 <> 'a' and var2 = 'b' and var3 = 'c' and var4 = 'd'
```

I would recommend an index on `(var2, var3, var4, var1)`.  The query will then use this index to find the rows you want.  The query can still take a long time if the result set is large.

That said, the issue that you are facing sounds like a "cold cache" issue.  You don't specify the database, but in general, databases start with no data in memory.  When you fetch data pages or index pages, then the database caches them in memory so subsequent access is much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the index idea. I will try it out. Can you explain more about the cold caching? My naive idea was that caching would make rerunning the exact same query faster, but it seems to improve performance of queries with the same restrictions.

Comment: @bab689 . . . It just means that the data/index pages are loaded into memory, saving on the I/O time.  They can help any query that accesses similar pages.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon pointed out, indexes are important and you need to resolve the conflict in your SQL statement. Did you mean this?

```
sql = "Select * from table where var1 != 'a' and var2 = 'b' and (var3 = 'c' OR var3 = 'd')"
```

Also, it is a good idea to consider whether or not you need all these statements.  How many rows are there where var1 is a, var2 is not b, and var3 is something other than c or d?  If it is a very small number, you may want to consider filtering results in your code rather than in the SQL statement.

Sometimes you can see a performance improvement with a subquery in the where clause (WHERE var IN (a, b, c) AND var NOT IN (b, e)), or by selecting individual columns or count(*) instead of *.

Hope this helps you :)